# Surface area defined as line length, why is this wrong?

Tags: geometry, area, surfaces

Let's take, for simplicity a square with side length A

The area is given by A^2 .

Now let's imagine we want to "paint" the surface area of this square with a single, uninterrupted, line.

We start at the bottom left corner, and move up the square's side with our line for its length, A, then once we are on the adjacent side edge we move right along it for a length D, then down again for A, then right for D, then up for A etc. Eventually we end up in one of the right corners, and complete our drawing by moving down (or up) once more for A.

The formula of our line length is given by

(A + D) * (A / D) + A

Where A+D is the length of one "step" of our iteration, A/D is the number of steps we take, and the final + A is the remaining side.

If we take the limit of this length for D -> 0, we end up diverging to infinity (A^2/D is the core term), very far from the expected A^2.

Conceptually, I can understand that a line cannot fill an area, as there are dimensionally more points, but I don't see what's wrong with this construction by itself, as it's not that different than the one for integration by segments.

What's wrong exactly here?

Comment: Why do you expect the limit of that length to give you the area? To me, it's not very surprising that the length in your construction tends to infinity, given that the square can be considered as the union of *uncountably* many line segments of length $A$. To get the area, you should (intuitively speaking) multiply each segment by its infinitesimal width $dx$ and add up all those uncountably many infinitesimal areas by integration to get the total area $\int_0^A A \, dx = A^2$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Right so the problem here is that, since I'm using a line with no width, the lack of dx integration doesn't "even out" the higher dimensionality (what you call uncountability) of the real (as in belongs to R) length. Makes sense. Can you formalize this as an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you view the square as the union of vertical line segments of length $A$, one segment for each $x \in [0,1]$, then their total length is clearly infinite (since they are infinitely many). So in your construction, when you use more and more of these segments, it's not too surprising that the length grows without bound.

The intuitive way to think about the area (at least in calculus) is that each segment has an “infinitesimal” area $A \, dx$ (the finite height $A$ times an infinitesimally small width $dx$), and you get that total area of the square by “adding up” (integrating) all these uncountably many infinitesimal area contributions:
$$
\int_0^A A \, dx = A^2
.
$$

Comment: You have a small error - the domain is $x\in [ 0,A]$, and your integration should therefore go from $0$ to $A$. $$\int_0^A A \,dx = \left[ Ax \right]_0^A = A^2$$

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: Oops, of course! Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \text {Paint Brush width= each strip width } = D = A/n, \;n = A/D\; $$

$$\text {Total painted Area} = D \cdot A \cdot n = A^2 . $$

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but that's not the question. If I were to apply the same process you described to the limit mentioned I'm effectively using the integral formula (segments size -> 0), which is not the same question about why "line length" here diverges. I know the "right" formula, the question is why this is wrong exactly